# Where should I add my PATH's?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need the command 'rails' to be added permanently to the PATH variable. I'm not sure if this should be happening automatically, as every rails guide seem to assume doing 'rails something' will work right after installing it. The same happened with other programs, so I think I'm the problem.

I searched this but I found many options, not sure which is the most appropriate way:

option 1) edit ~/.bashrc

option 2) edit ~/.profile

option 3) put a script into /etc/profile.d/

I haven't tried them yet, I don't want to make a mess in the system.

Any suggestions?

ps. I'm on Ubuntu 11 server edition 64 bits

My final choice: I used ~/.bashrc for the sake of simplicity, I only needed to open a new terminal after adding the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect the machine remotely using console, then `.bash_profile` is used. But if you're already logged into the machine and just open a new terminal window, then `.bashrc` is used. You might also find some useful info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment).